# Pointer going out of bounds resulting in segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic, double-pointer

I am currently completing an assignment thats supposed to demonstrate my understanding on how to effectively use pointers and pointer arithmetic within a 2D array. The purpose of the function below is to access and check the surrounding locations within the array for any given location. If the surrounding locations are out of bounds the location is ignored and not checked. Unfortunately, when the function is called it results in a segmentation fault(memory core dump).

After running my debugger and documenting my results that can be found [here][1], I was able to determine that the error lies with `bottom = *boardArr.` My original reasoning for setting bottom equal to *boardArr was to set bottom to  the beginning address of the boardArr so that I could transverse through the other locations adjacent to it so that i could check them using pointer arithmetic, but that has not been the case. I have tried setting `bottom = nullptr` as well but returns nothing to the console. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to go about fixing my problem that would be greatly appreciated.

Update: instructions for rules can be found below:

SimBacteria Rules

- Each cell has at most 8 neighbors (cells on the edge of the world
  will have fewer)
- If a cell contains an organism and has fewer than 2 neighbors, the
  organism dies of loneliness. o A neighbor is an organism in one of
  the 8 spots (or fewer if on the edge) around a cell
- If a cell contains an organism and has more than 3 neighbors, it
  dies from overcrowding.
- If an empty location has exactly three neighbors, an organism is
  born in that location.
- All births and deaths happen simultaneously. o No changes should be
  made to the world until all cells have been tested.

//Simulation games remain a popular genre of video games and you have decided to capitalize on their success by designing SimBacteria.
// Given an area randomly populated by single cell organisms, players will be able to watch their cultures thrive (or die) throughout many generations of bacteria.
//Your program will drive the simulation and display each generation before recording the last generation into a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>



using namespace std;
bool  inbounds( int &rows, int &cols, int i, int j);
void rules(char** boardArr, int cols,  int rows, char** updateArr);
int update(char**boardArr);
char tmp;
int main()
{

    char**boardBegin;//reset pointers
    char**UboardBegin;//resets pointers
    char**updateArr;
    char**boardArr;
    char*ptr;
    int gen;
    char check;
    fstream inFile;//open file
    int rows=0;
    int cols =0;
    string line;//read each char from file
    cout <<"\t"<< "Bacteria Generation Simulation" << "\n\n";

    inFile.open("simbac.txt", ios::in |ios::out);
//input validation
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    }

    cout<<"Enter generation amount: ";
    cin>>gen;
    while(gen <= 0 || gen > 10) //input validation
    {
        //acount for char entry later
        cout<<"Error, try again\n";
        cin>>gen;
    }
    //cout<<"Before loop"<<endl;



//determine number of cols and rows

    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        cols = line.length();
        rows++;
    }

//parsing file into boardArr
        boardArr = new char*[rows];
        updateArr = new char*[rows];
        boardBegin = boardArr;
        UboardBegin = updateArr;
        for(int i =  0; i < rows; i++, boardArr++,updateArr++)
        {
            boardArr[i] = new char[cols];
            updateArr[i] = new char[cols];

            inFile.clear();//resets file read
            inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);//resets pos of file read
        }

        boardArr = boardBegin;//Resets pointer
        updateArr=  UboardBegin;//Resets pointer
        //cout<<"Entering "<<endl;
        inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

//Inserting stuff into 2d arry
        for(int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) //rows
        {

            //cout<<"Inside inserting stuff into 2d arry"<<endl;

            ptr = *boardArr;
            //cout<< i<<endl;
            for(int j = 0; j <= cols; j++) //cols
            {
                cout<<*ptr;
                ptr++;//moves to the next address
            }

            cout<<endl;
            }
            //run until reaches gen amount
for(int i = 0 ; i <= gen; i++)
  {
      //cout<<"Entering "<< i<<endl;

    rules(boardArr,cols, rows, updateArr);


  }
  return 0;
    }







//move through string by parsing  to insert each char into array element position

void rules(char** boardArr,int cols, int rows, char**updateArr)
{
  char *current;
  char *pos;
  char *upos;
  char n;
  char* top = nullptr;
  char* bottom = nullptr;
  //cout<<"Before  for loop"<<endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++, boardArr++,updateArr++) //rows
  {
      char ncount = 0;
      if(i < rows -1)
      {

          boardArr++;
         // bottom = *boardArr;
          boardArr--;//resets
      }
      else
      {
          bottom = nullptr;
      }
      pos = *boardArr;//
      //cout<<"Before  for loop"<<endl;

      for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++, pos++, upos++) //cols
      {
          //<<"Inside for loop"<<endl;

          //n = *pos;
          *upos = n;
          if(j != 0)
          {
              pos--;
              if(*pos = '*')
              {
                  ncount++;
                  //moves to the right
              }
              pos++;
              if(j != cols -1)
              {
                  pos++;
                  if(*pos = '*')
                  {
                      ncount++;

                  }
                  pos--;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              pos++;
              if(*pos = '*')
              {
                  ncount++;

              }
              pos++;
          }


          if(top != nullptr)
          {
              pos = j + top;//moves to the top right
              if(*pos = '*')
              {
                  ncount++;

              }
              pos++;

              if(j != 0)
              {
                  pos--;
                  if(*pos = '*')
                  {
                      ncount++;
                      //moves to the right
                  }
                  pos++;
                  if(j != cols -1)
                  {
                      pos++;
                      if(*pos = '*')
                      {
                          ncount++;

                      }
                      pos--;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  pos++;
                  if(*pos = '*')
                  {
                      ncount++;

                  }
                  pos++;
              }
          }

          if(bottom != nullptr)
          {
              pos = j + bottom;
              if(*pos = '*')
              {
                  ncount++;

              }
              pos++;

              if(j != 0)
              {
                  pos--;
                  if(*pos = '*')
                  {
                      ncount++;
                      //moves to the right
                  }
                  pos++;
                  if(j != cols -1)
                  {
                      pos++;
                      if(*pos = '*')
                      {
                          ncount++;

                      }
                      pos--;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  pos++;
                  if(*pos = '*')
                  {
                      ncount++;

                  }
                  pos++;
              }


          }
          //If a cell contains an organism and has fewer than 2 neighbors, the organism dies of loneliness.
          if(ncount < 2 || ncount > 3)
          {
              *upos = ' ';
          }
          else if(ncount == 3)
          {
              *upos = '*';
          }






      }
      top = *boardArr;

  }
}
/*
bool  inbounds( int &rows, int &cols, int i, int j)
{
if();


}

int update(char**boardArr)
{
// boardArr = uboardArr;//copies content from old board into new board

//make changes to uboardArr here


//return UboardArr;
}
//open file print

*/
```

Comment: Looking at the complexity of the code (all those ++, --, + 1, -1 and the large number of variables), it is not surprising that you get a segmentation fault. I would suggest you to try to simplify the code. Also splitting the code in multiple functions and doing unit testing could also help.

Comment: Use the debugger on non optimized (DEBUG) code. It is very hard to debug optimized code as code can be reordered or even removed and some variables not be available for inspection (as it seems to be the case if the linked document).

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Lol my apologies. I didn't want to make it seem like I was wanting someone to do my HW for me I'll edit it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . I thought it would be more logical to create this as a whole rather than dividing it into 3 functions (top check, midcheck, bottom check) since they would all have similar sequences.

Comment: GoL standard rules?

Comment: You thought it would be more logical to create this as a whole??   Completely the wrong approach.   Practically, code is easier to get right by breaking it into small pieces, getting the pieces working correctly, and then getting the pieces working together correctly.   Trying to create it as a whole - as you describe - is more error prone, since it means you need to track all the details at once.   Humans cannot track that many things at once (upper limit is about seven) in a coherent manner, so often works out that tweaking one part of the code to fix a problem introduces other problems.

Comment: @Swordfish 8m not sure what that is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Tray Conway's Game of Life.

Comment: @Swordfish yes, it's a slight variation that involves bacteria simulation

Comment: @Tray Same rules as GoL?

Comment: @Swordfish I updated the post to include the rules

Comment: @Tray Try again.

Comment: @Swordfish link not working?

Comment: @Tray Try for yourself?

Comment: @Swordfish okay should be working now

Comment: @Tray Both links ask for username and pwd. Also note that it is discouraged to link external sources if the information can be included in the question.

Comment: @Swordfish okay then ill just copy the text and do it that way